# Where to run python file on Remote Debian Sever

Tags: python, debian, remote-server, directory-structure

I have written a python script that is designed to run forever. I load the script into a folder that I made on my remote server which is running debian wheezy 7.0. The code runs , but it will only run for 3 to 4 hours then it just stops, I do not have any log information on it stopping.I come back and check the running process and its not there. Is this a problem in where I am running the python file from? The script simply has a while loop and writes to an external csv file. The file runs from /var/pythonscript. The folder is a custom folder that I made. There is not error that I receive and the only way I know how long the code runs is by the time stamp on the csv file. I run the .py file by ssh to the server and sudo python scriptname.I also would like to know the best place in the linux debian directory to run python files from and limitations concerning that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Find out why "it just stops" and you'll probably find your answer. In it's current form, your question doesn't have enough information for anyone to help.

Comment: Information like how you run the script, log messages the script produces, location of the script are all helpful. Let us know what you've tried to find out the cause/fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're stuffed.

Your problem is:

1. You have a script, which produces no error messages, no logging, and no other diagnostic information other than a single timestamp, on an output file.
2. Something has gone wrong.

In this case, you have no means of finding out what the issue was.  I suggest any of the following:

1. either adding logging or diagnostic information to the script.
2. Contacting the developer of the script and getting them to find a way of determining the issue.
3. Delete the evidently worthless script if you can't do either option 1, or 2, above, and consider an alternative way of doing your task.

Now, if the script *does* have logging, or other diagnostic data, but you delete or throw them away, then that's your problem and you need to stop discarding this useful information.

EDIT (following comment).

At a basic level, you should print to either stdout, or to stderr, that alone will give you a huge amount of information. Just things like, "Discovered 314 records, we need to save 240 records", "Opened file name X.csv, Open file succeeded (or failed, as the case may be)", "Error: whatever", "Saved 2315 records to CSV".  You should be able to determine if those numbers make sense. (There were 314 records, but it determined 240 of them should be saved, yet it saved 2315? What went wrong!? Time for more logging or investigation!)

Ideally, though, you should take a look at the logging module in python as that will let you log stack traces effectively, show line numbers, the function you're logging in, and the like.   Using the logging module allows you to specify logging levels (eg, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR), and to filter them or redirect them to file or the console, as you may choose, without changing the logging statements themselves.

When you have a problem (crash, or whatever), you'll be able to identify roughly where the error occured, giving you information to either increase the logging in that area, or to be able to reason what must have happened (though you should probably then add enough logging so that the logging will *tell* you what happened clearly and unambiguously).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I wrote the script myself. What should I google search for to find relevant info about logging things with python and bash.